# PHP 7 Upgrade Issues with Depreciated Style

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.6

I'm punching above my class here but I'm hoping to get some help. 
I ran a PHP checker to see if we can upgrade a very old site to PHP 7. 
One of the common warnings I get is

**411 | WARNING | Use of deprecated PHP4 style class constructor is not supported since PHP 7.**

When I go to that line it always has something like this.

```
class twitter_feed_widget extends WP_Widget {

function twitter_feed_widget () {
    $widget_ops = array('description' => 'Twitter feed widget');
    $this->WP_Widget('twitter_feed_widget', 'Twitter Feed', $widget_ops);
}
```

From what I gathered I need to change the

```
function twitter_feed_widget ()
```

to `function __construct()`.

But how does the function know what widget to grab when I remove the name of the specific widget? Is it from the class at the top?

Sorry for the basic question and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Correct, it'll understand the class name.

Comment: _"Is it from the class at the top?"_ Yep.

Comment: Both functions are called by instancing `new twitter_feed_widget()`, i.e. the class name.

Comment: As you already understood, all you need to do is to change the function name to __construct(), as for your second question, what do you mean remove of a specific widget?